# avoid meteor load scripts on <head>

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Its there a way to run scripts after some template load?

Im totally noob on meteor, so i want to load my `scripts.js` after my template.html get loads, without meteor i put thats scripts on the body and works, but now im using meteor its seems like meteor load all scripts at same time on the  and the problem its like i need to load first the template and later the script

so my question its there a way to put a script on somewhere and call him when the template finish load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be off here, but I think you'll want to think of this a bit differently. The whole idea behind Meteor is to not care about forcing the load order of scripts. If you need to fire some event after your page is loaded, put it in a `Template.rendered` callback. Try reading this https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_rendered to get a better idea. This way the template is ready and you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Yep i did that yesterday and worked, sorry for not uopdate the answer

Answer (score 1):

First, put classie.js and sidbarEffects.js into the public directory so Meteor doesn't bundle them.

Then add the following inside any body tag:

```
    <div id="bottomJS"></div>
    <script>
        var classyJS = document.createElement('script');
        classyJS.src = "js/classie.js";
        var bottomJsTag = document.getElementById('bottomJS');
        bottomJsTag.parentNode.insertBefore(classyJS, bottomJsTag);

        var sidebarEffectsJS = document.createElement('script');
        sidebarEffectsJS.src = "js/sidebarEffects.js";
        var bottomJsTag = document.getElementById('bottomJS');
        bottomJsTag.parentNode.insertBefore(sidebarEffectsJS, bottomJsTag);
    </script>
```

You can leave modernizer.custom.js on the root of the client directory.

I put normalize.css inside client lib and the remaining css in client/css.

This solution works for me, good luck. Solution inspired by the YouTube API implementation I did a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I just re-read your question, and noticed you want to load your `.js` after your html loads. Is there any particular reason this is the case? Normally this is the exact opposite of what you want.

Granted I am understanding you correctly, in your folder structure, you should have a `client` folder. In that `client` folder, create a `lib` folder. Anything in that folder will load before anything else.

[Here](https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#user-content-where-should-i-put-my-files) is something from a solid unofficial FAQ about Meteor that will be a really good help while learning some of the basics of Meteor. It is supported by a very active member of the Meteor community.

Comment: hello sean, yea sorry about the question its just very bad formulated, but look the point its this, im trying to use this http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenLayoutPageTransitions/ layout on my meteor app, but its just don't working on meteor, on a simple page without it work just like calling the 2 js on the <body> and works, but here on meteor its just don't working so after looking something it seem like i need to first load the html layout and after the .js so i guess it will work

Comment: o and yea i have that structure on my app

Comment: Well, if you have the proper structure where you are putting the `.js` files in the proper lib folder it should work just fine. I can think of any time where you would want to load `.js` after the page has loaded. There just must be a minor error in how your setting up your folders.